# php include from the root direcory

Tags: php, include, directory

I'am setting up a site on 000webhost, and I'm having trouble doing a include. The site works with a lot of templates, like head.php, footer.php etc. These are stored in the includes folder, but the problem is that I need to access the files from **another** sub directory. I've already tried DOCUMENT_ROOT, but I get an error message. The same happens when I try **/public_html/includes etc**. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

If your current path is `/public_html/path`, then use `../include/` to access `/public_html/include/`

Answer (score 0):

If you need to reach some subfolder ( not under your existing webroot ) , try using symlinks...

or

if under your webroot then  add 
include_once "includes/somefile.php" wherever you need to include this file.
This assumes that includes is a subdir in your web application folder.